# why can I not recreate my blockchain.info addresses?

Tags: blockchain

I'm trying to generate a list of all my Addresses ever used on blockchain.info wallet with balances prior to august 1st,2017. i used the tool below to do this:
https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39
But when I feed this with my Twelve word backup phrased from blockchain wallet, It does not work and gives the error "one word is not listed in dictionary!"
what's the issue? what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue! the point was that in fact I should have removed 1. , 2. etc before my 12 word seed phrase.pretty funny, huh? :)

Comment: You can click the check mark button by your own answer, to mark this question as resolved.  Otherwise, the system will think it does not have any satisfactory answer and will keep trying to encourage others to answer it, which is annoying.